# How to sort posts inside categories

Tags: posts, order, sort

A weird question from my friend - is it possible in WordPress to sort posts inside categories? Right now the sort order is the default. He shows on specific pages posts from different categories. That's why using some drag-drop mechanism he would like to sort the posts inside categories like:

```
+ CATEGORY 1
  - postsA
  - postsB
  - postsC
```

into:

```
+ CATEGORY 1
  - postsC
  - postsA
  - postsB
```

is it possible? even using a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [This Plugin](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/) is what you are looking for.